# Devolver el valor por defecto de un texto con Jquery

Tags: jquery, mediaqueries

tengo este simple script que cambia el texto cuando le das click y lo devuelve al original cuando le vuelves a dar click, algo sencillo, pero tengo una duda y no se como resolverla. ¿Como se puede hacer para devolver el valor por defecto a un texto si es cambiado cuando da click? , para explicarme mejor, en este caso defino una media query desde javascript, si la pantalla es menor a 800px , el texto del boton debe cambiar al original ('Texto original') si es que le has dado click al boton estando en una pantalla mayor a 800px. Ejem: estoy en una pc de 1920x1080 y le doy click al boton, el texto cambia por ---> 'El texto ha sido cambiado' , entonces si yo redimensiono el tamaño de la pantalla por 800px, el boton con el texto modificado debe volver al texto original ---> 'Texto original' sin darle click al boton.

```js
$(function(){
    const changeResize = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 800px)');
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var text_button = $(this).text();
    if(text_button == 'Texto original'){
        $(this).text('El texto ha sido cambiado');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Texto original');
    }
    if(changeResize.matches){
        $(this).text().reset(); /* <------ Esto intenté y ha simple vista se ve que esta mal */
    }

});
    function changeColorBody(){
    if(changeResize.matches){
        $('.container').css('background','darkred');
    } else {
        $('.container').removeAttr('style');
        }
    }

    changeColorBody();

    window.addEventListener('resize', changeColorBody)

    });
```

```css
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.container{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
background: orange;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
background: lightblue;
}
button{
padding: 10px 60px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: none;
border-radius: 10px;
background: black;
color: lightblue;
font-family: cursive;
margin: 10px;
}
button:hover{
cursor: pointer;
}
button:focus{
outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <div class="btn">
    <button>Texto original</button>
    </div>

    <div class="btn">
    <button>Texto original</button>
    </div>

    <div class="btn">
    <button>Texto original</button>
    </div>

    <div class="btn">
    <button>Texto original</button>
    </div>
        </div>
```

Bueno espero me puedan ayudar, lo seguiré intentando mañana :)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que me estaba ahogando en un vaso de agua al hacer esto, la solucion mas facil es agregar un .text() con el valor de ----> Texto original dentro de la funcion ChangeColorBody, se va aplicar para todo tipo de pantalla. Cada vez que se cambia el tamaño de pantalla, el texto vuelve al original.

```js
$(function(){
    const changeResize = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 800px)');

$('button').on('click', function(){
    var text_button = $(this).text();
    if(text_button == 'Texto original'){
        $(this).text('El texto ha sido cambiado');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Texto original');
    }

});
    function changeColorBody(){
  $('button').text('Texto original')
    if(changeResize.matches){
    
        $('.container').css('background','darkred');
    } else {
        $('.container').removeAttr('style');
        }
    }

    changeColorBody();

    window.addEventListener('resize', changeColorBody)

    });
```

```css
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.container{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
background: orange;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
background: lightblue;
}
button{
padding: 10px 60px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: none;
border-radius: 10px;
background: black;
color: lightblue;
font-family: cursive;
margin: 10px;
}
button:hover{
cursor: pointer;
}
button:focus{
outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
        </div>
```